# eclipse could not find zXingJune2010.apk

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, zxing

I downloaded a zxing liberaries and zxing project and I imported them to my workspace. when I tried to run the project, eclipse generated an error as follows:

```
[2012-09-11 13:17:04 - zXingJune2010] Could not find zXingJune2010.apk!
```

after importing the project into my workspace i changed the build path to import the required libraries, and there were no errors and then i tried to run the app then eclipse generated the foremention error

how to fix this error?

Comment: Have you set zxing libraries to be _libraries_? Somwewhere in project properties I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try cleaning the project

Mark zxing libraries as a library (Properties>Android>Is Library) and make sure it is added to the zxing project

Then right-click the project and click on Android Tools>Fix Project Properties

This should fix your problem.